# Как создать контроллер для параметра?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

Есть список задач (экземпляры класса Task).
У каждой задачи есть приоритет (поле типа `integer`).
На html страничке нужно по клику на кнопки "вверх" "вниз" повышать/понижать приоритет задачи.

Я хотел сделать что-то типа этого (повышать приоритет по клику на `%i.fa.fa-caret-up`)

```
= link_to task, remote: true, method: :put do
%i.fa.fa-caret-up
```

но это не правильно.

Был также совет сделать контроллер `TaskPrioritiesController`, но с этим я пока не разобрался, и не понял как этот контроллер будет работать.

Собственно, вопрос в том, как мне правильно организовать изменение параметра `priority` у экземпляра класса `Task`?

p.s. За литературу по этой теме тоже буду благодарен

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки:

```
= link_to 'Увеличить', up_task_path(task), remote: true
= link_to 'Уменьшить', down_task_path(task), remote: true
```

В routes.rb:

```
resources :tasks do
  member do
    get :up
    get :down
  end
end
```

В контроллере:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:up, :down]

  def up
    @task.up! # Реализация внутри модели
  end

  def down
    @task.down!  # Реализация внутри модели
  end

  private

  def set_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Вот [тут](http://maxopka.su/2015/06/04/rails-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-resources-collection-member/) я когда-то писал про `member`.

Comment: Думаю, поможет. но это не CRUD путь, так сказать.

Comment: А если в вашем варианте попробовать использвать метод PATCH вместо метода PUT?

Answer (score 1):

#### Здесь очень много "если".

В Rails принято реализовывать `update`-экшн через метод `update` у модели. **Если** вы сделали именно так, то, возможно, изменения на сервере вам не потребуются вовсе.

**Если** повышение приоритета состоит только из присвоения нового значения приоритета (а остальное в коллбэках или не требуется), то достаточно просто вызвать уже существующий экшн `update` с набором параметров, содержащим новое значение приоритета **и только его**.

То есть, условно, вам потребуется сделать вызов `TasksController#update` глаголом `PATCH` с параметрами вроде таких:

```
{
  task: {
    priority: 42
  }
}
```

И новое значение приоритета запишется в задачу.

Если вы хотите ограничиваться CRUD'ом, то других вариантов у вас особо-то и нету. **А этот вариант будет довольно "весело" поддерживать**, если у вас приоритеты должны составлять непрерывную последовательность чисел на манер `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`...

---

Остаётся вопрос о том, как вы собирались обновлять DOM, сдвигать задачу, но это уже совсем другая история...